# Shortest path without diagonally moves

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I know there is alot of shortest path Algorithms but i want to ask if there any modifications can be done , to make some Algorithms like a* or Dijkstra chose the shortest path but without the diagonally moves so up and

down and right and left are the allowed moves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you probably want is A* (if you want a short path over a large map with some coherent obstacles), though you might just need Dijkstra's (if you must have the mathematically shortest path, or if the map doesn't have any real relation to anything physical). You simply disallow diagonal moves and you might get better results if you use Manhattan distance as your heuristic for A*. For Dijkstra's, the graph has no diagonal links.